# Tar Backup ending with error

Tags: backup, tar

I want to backup my root dir with Tar but getting this error:

```
beende mit fehlerstatus aufgrund vorheriger fehler
```

In English:

```
Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
DATE=$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S)
BACKUP_DIR="/mnt/disk/public/Backup"
SOURCE="/"
EXCLUDE="--exclude=/mnt/disk/public"
tar -vzcpf $BACKUP_DIR/backup-$DATE.tar.gz $SOURCE $EXCLUDE
```

What is the error here?

Comment: Your `--exclude` option might be being ignored (and parsed as a path) because it follows the source.  You should move it to before the other options, i.e. `tar $EXCLUDE -vzcpf ...`.

Comment: I have it with tar EXCLUDE... but no change. But I get the same error!

Comment: What other error messages is tar displaying? You may need to exclude some pseudo-filesystems such as `/sys`, `/proc`, and `/dev`.

Comment: The answer depends on what the full output on stdout and stderr is.

Answer (score 0):

The error means that `tar` is unable to add some files to the tarball.

In fact you are backing up everything from `/` which is certain to result to an error.

Try to replace the EXCLUDE variable with this:

```
EXCLUDE="--exclude=dev --exclude=mnt --exclude=proc --exclude=run --exclude=sys --exclude=tmp"
```

and omit the `-v` flag so you can reduce the amount of output messages and pinpoint the error.